# Existence and uniqueness for $y' = \sqrt y+1$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, dynamical-systems

Given that $y' = \sqrt{y}+1$, $y(0)=0$, $x\in [0,1] =: I$, how does one show that this ODE has a unique solution on I? I was thinking that one might be able to show that this ODE satisfies a Lipschitz condition on some $J \subset I$. We might consider $\lvert \sqrt{y_1} - \sqrt{y_2} \lvert^2 = \lvert y_1 - 2\sqrt{y_1 y_2}+y_2\lvert\le2\lvert y_1-\sqrt{y_1y_2}+y_2 \lvert = 2\lvert -y_1+\sqrt{y_1^2+y_2^2}-y_2 \lvert$ $\le2\lvert -y_1+\sqrt{y_1^2+2y_1y_2+y_2^2}-y_2 \lvert $ 
$=2\lvert -y_1+y_1+y_2-y_2 \lvert \le 2\lvert -y_1+y_2\lvert + 2\lvert y_1-y_2 \lvert = 4\lvert y_1 - y_2\lvert$.

I'm concerned, however, that one would need to arrive at something like $K\lvert y_1-y_2 \lvert^2$ in this case.

Would appreciate some clarification.

Comment: The square root function is not lipschitz on any interval around zero.

Comment: You have some shady inequalities there, since the first term in your third line is zero.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: you're correct. However, I don't see any errors in my inequalities. So, if I'm correct then I have shown that $\lvert \sqrt{y_1} - \sqrt{y_2}\lvert \le 0$ on $[0, 1]$, which implies uniqueness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write the differential equation as $$ \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{y}} \dfrac{dy}{dx} = 1 $$
We can write this as $\dfrac{d}{dx} F(y(x)) = 1$, where $$F(y) = \int_0^y \dfrac{ds}{1+\sqrt{s}}$$
Thus we must have $F(y(x)) = x + c$ for some constant $c$.  Since $F(0)=0$, the initial condition $y(0)=0$ tells us $c = 0$.  Since $F$ is an increasing function, $F(y(x)) = x$ specifies $y(x)$ uniquely for any $x$.

Comment: This is incredibly nice!

Comment: Well, it's just taking advantage of the fact that the equation is separable.  Something like $y' = 1 + x^2 + \sqrt{y}$ would be harder: I guess you might be able to use Grönwall's inequality.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I'm impressed by your mathematical savvy.